# How To create Ansible variable from string

Tags: ansible

For Example:

I Have Variable {{ ami_redhat_7_2 }} That I want to use

```
vars:
  OsType: redhat
  OsVersion: '7_2'

tasks:
- debug: 'msg="{{ ami_{{OsType}}_{{ OsVersion }} }}"'
```

I got Error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'. String: {{ ami_{{ OsType }}_{{ OsVersion }} }}"
}
```

Comment: Did you try this :  
    - debug: msg="{{vars["ami_" ~ OsType ~ "_" ~ OsVersion]}}"

Answer (score 12):

'root' variables with dynamic names is a tricky thing in Ansible.
If they are host facts, you can access them like this:

```
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ami_'+OsType+'_'+OsVersion] }}
```

If they are play-bound variables, you can access them via undocumented `vars` object:

```
{{ vars['ami_'+OsType+'_'+OsVersion] }}
```

But they will never get templated, because `vars` is treated in a special way.

The easiest way for you is some dict with predefined name and dynamic key names, like:

```
ami:
   redhat_7_2: 827987234/dfhksdj/234ou234/ami.id
```

And to access it, you can use:

```
{{ ami[OsType+'_'+OsVersion] }}
```

P.S. and remove quotes around `msg` as suggested in other answer.

Comment: There is a mention in FAQ: [if you need to use a dynamic variable use the hostvars or vars dictionary as appropriate](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names), so `vars` is documented :-)

Comment: It's so annoying that the vars it's not better documented.