# Ansible 2.2.1.0 with_subelements: ERROR! subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got 'incor'

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following problem:
When I use a variable with_subelements I have an error: ERROR! subelements    lookup expects a dictionary, got 'incor'
My hosts file:

```
[incor]
127.0.0.1
```

dir group_vars

```
group_vars
  --- all
  --- incor
           --- main.yml
```

group_vars/incor/main.yml

```
---
incor:
  - pfileurl: "http://domain/file1.jar"
    pfilename: "user1.jar"
    pfiletype: "lib"
    pfileset:
      - {type: "type1", reg: "reg1" }
      - {type: "type2", reg: "reg2" }

  - pfileurl: "http://domain/file2.jar"
    pfilename: "user2.jar"
    pfiletype: "lib"
    pfileset:
      - {type: "type1", reg: "reg1" }
      - {type: "type2", reg: "reg2" }
```

roles/p_get_file/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Download files
  get_url:
    url="{{ item.0.pfileurl }}"
    dest="{{ path }}{{ item.1.type }}/{{ item.1.reg }}/{{ item.0.pfilename }}"
    force="yes"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ projectname }}"
    - "pfileset"
  when: "'item.0.pfiletype is defined' and item.0.pfiletype == 'lib'"
  delegate_to: "127.0.0.1"
```

myplaybook.yml

```
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  roles:
    - { role: p_get_file }
```

start playbook

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml --extra-vars "hosts='incor' projectname='incor'"
```

Problem with variable {{ projectname }} in Ansible 1.9.4 it's work but
in Ansible 2.2.1.0 doesn't work:  ERROR! subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got 'incor'

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bare variables since Ansible 2.2.

In 1.9 it works because this syntax is acceptable:

```
  with_subelements:
    - incor
    - pfileset
```

In 2.2+ `incor` is treated like string.

The easiest way for you to fix this is to wrap your `incor` dict into some top-level dictionary like `projects`:

```
---
projects:
  incor:
    - pfileurl: "http://domain/file1.jar"
      pfilename: "user1.jar"
      pfiletype: "lib"
      pfileset:
        - {type: "type1", reg: "reg1" }
        - {type: "type2", reg: "reg2" }
    ...
```

And then access it like this:

```
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ projects[projectname] }}"
    - pfileset
```

Or you can [jump trough some hoops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40968307/2795592) to access root-level variable.

Comment: But now Ansible 2.2 see all variables in all directories Not only global_vars/incor/main.yml
`
global_vars/
  --- incor/
         --- main.yml
  --outcor/
        --- main.yml
`
and remember only last

Comment: Now I can't use variable `projects` in global_vars/incor/main.yml and global_vars/outcor/main.yml

Comment: You may want to change `hash_behaviour` setting to merge your projects dict (but it is not recommended in general) or revise your variables layout.

Comment: I tried to use `{{ vars[projectname] }}` but vaeiables `incor` raw    


`incor:
    - pfileurl: "http://domain/{{ projectname }}/file1.jar"
      pfilename: "user1.jar"
      pfiletype: "lib"
      pfileset:
        - {type: "type1", reg: "reg1" }
        - {type: "type2", reg: "reg2" }`


variables `{{ projectname }}` in `pfileurl` without object

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use [jump trough some hoops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40968307/2795592) `{{ vars[projectname] }}` but variables `incor` raw

```
incor: 
   - pfileurl: "http://domain/{{ projectname }}/file1.jar" 
     pfilename: "user1.jar" 
     pfiletype: "lib" 
     pfileset: 
       - {type: "type1", reg: "reg1" } 
       - {type: "type2", reg: "reg2" }
```

variables `{{ projectname }}` in `pfileurl` without object