# ansible join strings and variables in conditionals

Tags: ansible

I can't figure out how to join strings and {{ item }} in a conditional. I'm not sure if this is even possible or supported

here's my task block:

```
- name: enable repos
  command: "subscription-manager repos --enable {{ item }}"
  when: enable_repo_{{ item }} == 'yes'
  with_items:
    - rhel-7-server-rpms
    - rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
    - rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
    - rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.2-rpms
    - rhel-7-server-thirdparty-oracle-java-rpms
    - jws-3-for-rhel-7-server-rpms
```

the error I am getting is:

```
TASK [satellite_client : enable repos] *****************************************
fatal: [10.187.15.31]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'enable_repo_item == 'yes'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (enable_repo_item == 'yes'): 'enable_repo_item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/marcp/git/satellite_client/tasks/main.yml': line 21, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: enable repos\n  ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.187.15.31               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

How can I concatenate the string with {{ item }} or should I be doing this differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To create Ansible variable from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956212/how-to-create-ansible-variable-from-string)

Comment: I advice you to refactor your code and make `enabled_repos` list instead of multiple variables, this will make your playbook code much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. I got the same advice from freenode #ansible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition in `when` is supposed to be a Jinja2 expression (so you can think it's implicitly enclosed in `{{ ... }}` and thus cannot open another Jinja2 expressing inside).

You can use `vars` dictionary and pass the name of the variable as a concatenated string:

```
when: vars['enable_repo_' + item] == 'yes'
```

Comment: Waiting for Konstantin to wake up and complain that using `vars` dictionary is undocumented ;)

Comment: Just tried it. The code executes, but the task is getting skipped even though "enable_repo_xxx: yes" is set in defaults/main.yml. I suspect that the result of the concatenation is being taken as a string.

Comment: Use `debug` module and/or `-vvv` to troubleshoot.

Comment: And the result of the concatenation passed as a `vars` index should be a string.

Comment: anyway I can get the result of the concatenation treated as a variable, so that it evaluates to whatever value it is set?

Comment: I do not understand the question. In the meantime I verified my answer.

Comment: pardon me, I was unclear in my question (and grammar)

I have 2 variables on the conditional, one is 'item' that came from the loop, and another is the concatenation of the string 'enable_repo_' and whatever the value of 'item' is (is this what is called nested variable?). The code above evaluates 'item' but not the concatenation.

Also, it seems like my original post was a bad example due to the dashes in variable name (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8849). I've already corrected this, but my original problem stands.